# fullCalendar: Events aren't shown where expected on the grid

Tags: fullcalendar

Looked through the docs, but don't see why the events are placed incorrectly in my node app:

Global.js:

```
var eventList = [];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { 
var eventDesc = {};

  eventDesc = { title: 'Test', start: '2019-10-22', backgroundColor:'red' }; eventList.push( eventDesc );

eventDesc = { title: 'Test2', start: '2019-10-23T10:00:00', end: '2019-10-23T11:00:00', backgroundColor:'blue' };   eventList.push( eventDesc );

  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar'); 
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        defaultView: "timeGridWeek",
        height: "auto",
        slotDuration: "00:60:00",
        events: eventList,
        plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ]
      }
    );
  calendar.render(); 
});
```

**Getting the following view** (expect the blue event to be at 10 am on the grid, but it's off the grid entirely):
[grid view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g67vt.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Andy. Can I recommend taking some to structure your question so it is clear what you are asking for help with? Posing your problem as a question that can be answered would help. I would recommend reading the 'How do I ask a good question?' guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you customised the CSS of fullCalendar, or added some extra CSS of your own? That's almost always the cause of something like this. Go back to the default theme and see if you still have an issue

Comment: @ADyson I haven't customized the css that comes with fullCalendar, and in the Pug layout of the form in question I simply reference @fullcalendar/core/main.css and @fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css. The calendar element in the layout is just   div(id='calendar')

Comment: @ADyson BUT you led me down the right path! A reference to @fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css was missing! Looked everywhere but there - thanks